# Avoid repeatedly passing down same props to child components Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have tried searching for a while but couldn't find an answer that probably already is there.

In my application, I have found that I have to repeatedly pass down the same props to different child components. For example, I might have a method to toggle modal visibility in the parent components. Then some child components might need to access this methods to toggle modal.

```
<nav-bar 
  :toggleForm='toggleForm'>
</nav-bar>
<header-content
  :toggleForm='toggleForm'>
</header-content>
```

Is there a way to avoid repetition here? Because I would also have to write the same props types check & validations in different child components. It feels like a lot of repetition.

Would I have to use Vuex to solve this problem? Or could it be solved without adding a state management system?

Thank you.

Comment: yes you have to use vuex or alternative way would be using `events` to  change your child component property (in that case you dont need to pass props but still you need to listen for events and act according to that)

Comment: You can make a mixin that defines the props. You can also do `inheritAttrs: false` and `v-bind="attrs"` (google it)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. After some more searches based on the answers, these are the few solutions.

1. Use events for parent/child components: [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events)
2. Use events bus if it's between components: [doc](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)
3. Use Vuex